# How do you make a Bash script repeatedly run while holding down left mouse button?

Tags: bash, xdotool

So, I have a command (`xdotool click --delay 40 1`) I'm using to repeatedly click the left mouse button. As of now, the script is set up like this:

```bash
mouse="$(xinput --list | awk -F 'id=|\\[' '/mouse|Mouse/ {print $2}')"
mouse="${mouse//[[:space:]]}"

while :; do
    state="$(xinput --query-state 13)"

    while [[ "$state" == *"button[1]=down"* ]]; do
            xdotool click --delay 40 1
        done
done
```

The script functions, and activates whenever I press left mouse button, however it continues to repeat after I release the left mouse button. I believe in order to make this script function the way it was intended to I would have to stop the

```
xdotool click --delay 40 1
```

command whenever `button[1]=up`. The problem is, however, that I do not know how to do so. If someone would be able to help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You not ask the status in the while loop.

> ```
> while [[ "$state" == *"button[1]=down"* ]]; do
>         xdotool click --delay 40 1
>     done
> ```

When $state set, can not change....
Try the if instead of while.

Comment: When I change it to if the mouse behaves normally, instead of rapidly clicking whenever the left mouse button is held down.